# Возможно ли обновлять данные в одной строчке с выборкой по user_id, если строчек с одинаковым user_id несколько?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite3, aiogram

В моём боте пользователь поэтапно создаёт объявление и данные в столбцах с выборкой по его id обновляются методом

```
cursor.execute(f"UPDATE table SET name = '{message.text}' WHERE user_id = {message.chat.id}")
```

Но если пользователь захочет создать ещё одно объявление из за этого метода обновляются все строчки с его id и получаются одинаковыми. Есть ли способ избежать этого?

Comment: Надо отбор делать не по юзеру, а по идентификатору сообщения.

Comment: @Akina Но так как я использую StatesGroup и создание происходит поэтапно (то есть во время создания приходит не одно сообщение) идентификатор сообщения меняется и выборку по нему для заполнения оставшихся столбцов сделать не получается

Comment: Что за бред? какая разница, сколько сообщений создано? всё равно у каждого сообщения свой идентификатор - и уникальный, и неизменяемый.